# Como puedo traerme el constructor de la clase JFrame

Tags: java

Hola y buenas tengo un problema con la Clase JFrame. Bueno les explico lo que deseo hacer.
Yo estoy creando una clase MiVentana que extiende de JFrame, hasta ahí todo correcto, el problema surge cuando quiero hacer uso del constructo de la clase JFrame cuando me lo traigo con el método super para darle un título a la Ventana da error, pero la verdad no entiendo por qué.
Alguien me puede ayudar explicándome porque razón me da error el método super.
Aquí les dejo el código para que le echen un vistazo y así se entienda mejor el problema.

```
package com.christiandev.swing;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class MiVentana extends JFrame {
    
    public void Miventana () {

        super("Esta es mi segunda ventana.");
        setSize(500, 400);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

Nota: estoy utilizando visual estudio code

Comment: Al tener `void` lo haces método, no constructor.

Comment: Si tienes razón muchas gracias por el aporte.